# facebook app id for 2 apps

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

so i have 2 app with different package name .in facebook dashboard i have added one package name and key Hashes . i am able to use same a\c for different app also . so does facebook check key Hashes only not  package name ? so right i have one facebook id for 2 apps is it ok ?
  i am able to login with 2 different app with same facebook id 
so i have 2 andoridmainfest with productflovers

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
...
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
...
```

in this app id is same for both

in package name can we add 2 package or we have to create 2 facebook id ?